# Application not starting after pushing to Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku

This is the output of my "git push heroku master" command :

```
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /tmp/build_3kg6a8iex5xd6/target/scala-2.8.1/classes...
   [success] Total time: 8 s, completed Apr 22, 2012 4:54:01 PM
   [info] Wrote start script for mainClass := Some(JettyLauncher) to /tmp/build_3kg6a8iex5xd6/target/start
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 22, 2012 4:54:01 PM
   Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web
   Compiled slug size is 57.0MB
   Launching...  done, v23
   http://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

After this the Application is still not up. Tried heroku ps. It is not showing any process.

Contents of my Procfile :

```
web: target/start JettyLauncher
```

When I try foreman start, it is working fine.

Can somebody please help me find why the Application is not up after it is deployed to Heroku?

Comment: Check the heroku log(`heroku logs -t`), you can get more information about the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running

```
heroku scale web=1
```

If you've had a failed push before this heroku won't necessarily auto start the app